# Kineticjs: weird drag behavior. Does not register well

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, drag

I have kineticjs canvas that has a infinite draggable background. I have implemented the draggable background like this:

```
mainBodyBG.on('dragstart', function() {
  mainBodyBG.setX(0);
  mainBodyBG.setY(0);
});

 mainBodyBG.on('dragend', function() {
 mapXdisplacement += mainBodyBG.getX();
  console.log("mapXdisplacement: ", mapXdisplacement);
  mainBodyBG.setX(0);
  mainBodyBG.setY(0);
  dragBackgroundPos();
});
```

The thing is the value that I am printing to console in my 'dragend' event handler repeats occasionally. So I will go from dragging it several hundred pixels in a row successfully to having 2 or 3 drag attempts where it doesn't move at all. Is this a known bug or am I not doing something correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem! I abandoned my method of getting the x position difference that the drag event yielded and got the mouse position before and after dragging. So the modified code looks like:

```
var beforeMouse;
var afterMouse;

// my special event listener for infinite panning
mainBodyBG.on('dragstart', function() {
  mainBodyBG.setX(0);
  mainBodyBG.setY(0);
  var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
  beforeMouse = mousePos.x;
});

mainBodyBG.on('dragend', function() {

  var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
  afterMouse = mousePos.x;
  mapXdisplacement += (afterMouse - beforeMouse);
  mainBodyBG.setX(0);
  mainBodyBG.setY(0);
  dragBackgroundPos();

  console.log("mapXdisplacement: ", mapXdisplacement); 

});
```

and boom! this code allows for an infinite dragging.